# Why is it possible to use Lambda Expressions in Thread class?

Tags: lambda, java-8

Im learning Lambda Expressions and I know it is possible to use them for example in the Runnable functional interface and in Thread class.

I tried to create my own:

```
package tests;

public interface Blabla
{
    public void doStuff();
}
```

And this simple test compiled:

```
Blabla bla = () -> System.out.println("Lol");
```

Then I tried to make a class like Thread

```
package tests;

public class Dodo implements Blabla
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And this doesnt compile:

```
 Dodo dodo = () -> System.out.println("LoL");
```

And I cant find anywhere explaining how to create a class which allows the use of lambda expressions.

How can Thread allow the use of Lambda Expressions while not being an Interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can Thread allow the use of Lambda Expressions while not being an Interface?

I think you're a little confused by how the Thread class uses lambdas. The lambdas are not converted into an instance of the Thread class itself; instead, the lambdas are converted into an instance of a subclass the Runnable functional interface, which is then passed to a Thread constructor that has been [overloaded to take a Runnable object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-).

Thus, when you do something like this:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Lol")).start();
```

The lambda wasn't converted into the Thread object you're creating. Instead, it was converted into the Runnable object that is passed to the Thread constructor.

This is clearer if you separate the lambda from the Thread object:

```
Runnable temp = () -> System.out.println("Lol");

new Thread(temp).start();
```

It might help to think of a Thread *executing* a function rather than *being* a function. You have to keep the function that the Thread is executing distinct from the Thread itself.

Note that the way lambdas are converted into objects is an implementation detail and is subject to change in future Java releases (Java 1.8.0_11 is the most recent release at the time this answer was written). See Stuart Marks' comment below.

---

> And I cant find anywhere explaining how to create a class which allows the use of lambda expressions.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you wish to write a class such that you can create a lambda based on that class.

Unfortunately, you can't. Take a look at the Java Language Specification, section 15.27:

> Evaluation of a lambda expression produces an instance of a functional interface (§9.8).

The key point here is that the lambda is an instance of an *interface*. Thus, you can't use a lambda to directly subclass a class. The rationale for this can be found in [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008441.html) email by Brian Goetz in the JDK lambda-dev mailing list (Thanks to Stuart Marks for pointing this out!); in short, the decision was made at least partially so Java could continue to evolve in new directions.

What you *can* do is write a class whose constructor(s) and/or method(s) take one or more functional interfaces as arguments, letting you use the class with lambdas by passing instances of the functional interface around (like the Thread class). At the moment (and as far as I know), that's pretty much as good as it gets.

Comment: I was considering adding a section explaining why a lambda for a class doesn't make sense, but realized my knowledge of the area isn't solid enough to provide a satisfactory explanation, and any explanation I might provide would probably be complete. If you wish to hear my speculation, I can add it, though.

Comment: ahhh I didnt know Thread had a constructor with Runnable ^^' Thank you, that cleared up my doubts :) I also think lambda for classes are inconsistent, thats why Thread was confusing me. I would read your speculation tho ^^

Comment: @Xkynar Yep, no problem! When in doubt, use your IDE to inspect your code; you can learn a lot from the types your IDE shows when you hover over something. Added my speculation, hope it helps. Once you get familiar with Java, you should consider learning a functional language (Haskell seems to be pretty popular; my school teaches OCaml). It's a totally different perspective, and at least in this one case gives at least some reasoning behind the decisions made in Java's lambda implementation.

Comment: @Xkynar & user3580294: The rationale for disallowing lambdas to implement abstract classes is given by this [email message from Brian Goetz](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008441.html).

Comment: @StuartMarks Thanks for linking that! I wasn't aware that Brian Goetz had already written about the subject in such depth, and it made for quite some interesting reading. I've updated my answer to remove my guesses and added in a link to Brian's text, as well as what I hope is an OK summary.

Comment: @StuartMarks As a side note, is my description of lambdas representing objects accurate, given "lambdas are objects" isn't correct? Is there a better way to phrase that?

Comment: @user3580294 Close enough, I think. :-) Semantically a lambda wants to be a function, but even in Java 8 there are only primitives and objects. So today's lambda implementation is an object, and you can call `getClass()` etc. on it, but the results are unspecified and are subject to change. It might be more precise to say that a lambda is *converted into* an object that is an implementation of a functional interface.

Comment: @StuartMarks All right, updated my answer to use the more precise wording. Once again, thank you! Curious to see what you and the rest of the EG have in store for Java's future.

Comment: @user3580294 You're welcome! I'm not actually on the EG. You can follow along most Java development by signing up for various OpenJDK mailing lists at openjdk.java.net.

Comment: @StuartMarks Oops; my apologies for the mixup. I'll be sure to check those out, although I don't think I'll be posting in them any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is just a short form for writing an anonymous class, by using lambda expression we can declare methods wherever we want them without any name.

The sole purpose of writing an anonymous class object is to override its method and provide our own functionality but for that single method, we always need to declare the class. With lambda expression, we can eliminate the declaration of the anonymous class and we can simply provide the definition of the method.

For example we use below code to create a thread

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  System.out.println("Running thread using anonymous class");
  }
};
Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
```

But with lambda expression we can easily say

```
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Running thread using lambda expression");
Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
```

Or

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Running thread using lambda expression"));
```

So by writing `Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Running thread using lambda expression");` we told Java to create an anonymous object of type `Runnable` and provided the body for the `run()` method.

Lambda expression only works on `functional interfaces` (an interface which have only one method in it) because we are providing the body for the method on the fly. So if an interface have more than one method and we are are allowed to create a lambda on it then how compiler will identify to which method this provided method body belongs.

Th differences between Lambda Expression and Anonymous class are as follows

- An anonymous class object creates a separate class file after compilation which increases the size jar while after compilation Lambda expression becomes invokedynamic which dynamic language implementation.
- We can use this keyword to represent the current class in lambda expression while in the case of anonymous class this keyword represents that particular anonymous class.
- In the case of Lambda expression, we need to provide the function body only while in the case of anonymous class we need to write the redundant class definition.

You can read more on [Java Lambda Expression Explained with Example](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2016/06/java-lambda-expression-explained-with-example.html).